# Intercept javascript value setter

Tags: javascript, listener, prototype, interceptor, setter

How can I listen to value set on a variable or object property without losing other listeners.

for example

```
var myModel;
myModel = 10;
var myListener1 = function(oldVal, newVal) {
    //do stuff
}
var myListener2 = function(oldVal, newVal) {
    //do other stuff
}
```

here I want myListener1 and myListener2 to be called whenever a value is set for variable myModel. Later in other functions might also want to add another listener to myModel on setter so it shouldn't override existing ones.

I know there should be a way to do it with Object.defineProperty().
Also it would be good to have a solution cross browser for IE8+.

Comment: Not sure there's something built-in, you'd have to write some code. Look for "observer pattern" or "pub/sub" for examples (if I understand correctly).

Comment: You can use getters and setters, or `Object.watch()`

Comment: @JoeSimmons Can you give me an example? what do you mean by getters and setters?

Comment: Sure. You would have to use an object+property for this, but here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/grMng/

Comment: Greate, thanks for the answer and example. Is there a way to accomplish this for arrays as well? let's say I have "var array = [];" and I want to intercept when the elements of the array changes, for example removing an element adding one or replacing one with another value.

Comment: @JoeSimmons Could you write your answer in a separate post so I could choose it as the answer.

Comment: Sure, I posted the answer. As for arrays... I can't think of a way you could do it without using some irregular syntax... here's one way I might do it: http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/mLwAb/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the following method, you would have to use an object with a property, but it works.

---

```js
// this is very similar to using Object.watch()
// instead we attach multiple listeners
var myModel = (function () {
    var actualValue,
        interceptors = [];

    function callInterceptors(newValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < interceptors.length; i += 1) {
            interceptors[i](newValue);
        }
    }

    return {
        get value() {
            // user never has access to the private variable "actualValue"
            // we can control what they get back from saying "myModel.value"
            return actualValue;
        },

        set value(newValue) {
            callInterceptors(newValue);
            actualValue = newValue;
        },

        listen : function (fn) {
            if (typeof fn === 'function') {
                interceptors.push(fn);
            }
        }
    };
}());

// add a listener
myModel.listen(function (passedValue) {
    alert('You tried to set myValue to ' + passedValue);
});

// add another listener
myModel.listen(function (passedValue) {
    alert('AAARRG! Why did you modify that value to ' + passedValue + '?!?!');
});

// our functions are called when we
// modify our value
myModel.value = 10;
```

---

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/grMng/)

Answer (score 0):

only change the value of `myModel` through a function so you can run the listener functions  after/before the change.

```
var myModel = 10,
    myListener1 = function(oldVal, newVal) {
      // do stuff
    },
    myListener2 = function(oldVal, newVal) {
     // do other stuff
    },
    changeMyModel = function (value) {
      myListener1(myModel, value);
      myListener2(myModel, value);
      myModel = value;
      // do more stuff 
    };

   // changeMyModel(99) === myModel; true
```

OR

```
   var change = function (value) {
      myListener1(myModel, value);
      myListener2(myModel, value);
      return value;          
   };
   // myModel = change(45);
```

Comment: I want to be able to use regular assignment literal. like myModel = 10

Comment: i don't think thats possible with javascript, another possible way is: `myModel = change(10)` where `change` runs the listeners and returns 10